# How to use jQuery plugin (datatable) in lightning component - Salesforce?

Tags: jquery, datatables, salesforce

I am not able to call the jQuery datatable function. Below are the details -

DatatableApp.app -

```
<aura:application >
        <c:DatatableComponent />
</aura:application>
```

DatatableComponent.cmp -

```
<aura:component controller="DatatableController">
<!-- Static Resource details - jQuery js file --> (jQUerySource), jQuery Datatable file --> (jqueryDatatableJS) -->
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/1466061468000/jQuerySource,/resource/1466061531000/jqueryDatatableJS" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.jsLoaded}"/>
<!-- doInit method will call JS controller and then will get the details from Apex Controller and put in into the HTML using aura:iteration -->
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
              <table class="display" id="#sampleTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                  <aura:iteration items="{!v.cases}" var="case">
         <tr><td>1</td><td>{!case.Id}</td></tr>
       </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
 </aura:component>
```

DatatableComponentController.js -

```
({
    jsLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
        $('#sampleTable').DataTable();
    },
   doInit: function(component, event, helper) {    
      helper.getCaseList(component);   
   }
})
```

DatatableComponentHelper.js -

```
({
    getCaseList: function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getCases");
    var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        component.set("v.cases", actionResult.getReturnValue());            
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }   
})
```

DatatableController.apxc -

```
public class DatatableController {
       @AuraEnabled
       public static List<Case> getCases() {
           system.debug([SELECT Id FROM Case limit 10]);
           return [SELECT Id FROM Case limit 10];
       }   
    }
```

On click of preview button. I am getting this error -

[Option is not a constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zjfb.png)

I am using jQuery data table (https://datatables.net/) here.

Comment: I'm not sure i'd do it this way. Why not create the DataTable but then add rows to it in your action callback? I'm about to embark on doing something similar so I'd be interested in your results.

Comment: Actually, after reading around you'll need to call your DataTable in an `afterRender` function: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54106/how-to-use-jquery-or-any-js-lib-in-initial-post-rendering-of-lightning-compone